# this.hasErrors is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, typescript

I searched for a solution to my problem online but couldn't find any appropriate answer. Although there are tons of this particular question online.

In my typescript file I have the following three methods:

```
hasErrors() {
    // Checking for errors
}

saveItem() {
    if (this.hasErrors())
        return;
    // Save item
}

sendItemToAuthority() {
    if (this.hasErrors())
        return;
    // Send item to authority
}
```

Somehow `this.hasErrors()` inside `sendItemToAuthority()` isn't recognized as a function but in `saveItem()` it works without any problem. I get the following error in chrome developer tools:

> this.hasErrors is not a function

I found following possibility which didn't work for me either (same error message):

```
sendItemToAuthority() {
    var self = this;
    if (self.hasErrors)
        return;
    // Send item to authority
}
```

Could anyone lead me to a solution? I really don't get why it isn't working.

Comment: why is your error and your method name is different ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. In my constructor I had

```
this.saveItem = this.saveItem.bind(this);
```

but forgot to add

```
this.sendItemToAuthority = this.sendItemToAuthority.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

> saveItem() it works without any problem. I get the following error in chrome developer tools `this.hasErrors` is not a function

You most likely have the wrong `this`. Use an arrrow function : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was taking the wrong `this`. Check my own answer, I found the root of the problem.